# How to short this type of js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to minimize the code below and while maintaining the functionality.
please suggest me pattern which I can use for this kind of problems.

```
    // tb bid pickup location picker.
$('#--tb-bid-pickup-location').on('keyup', function () {
    toggler.toggler('#--tb-bid-location-picker', 'pulse');
});

// tb bid drop location picker.
$('#--tb-bid-destination-location').on('keyup', function () {
    toggler.toggler('#--tb-bid-location-picker', 'pulse');
});

// tb bid drop location picker.
$('#--tb-bid-vehicle-type').on('keyup', function () {
    toggler.toggler('#--tb-bid-truck-picker', 'pulse');
});
```

Comment: using multiple selectors (separated by `,`) and `this` in the event handler

Comment: You can minify your js [here](https://javascript-minifier.com/)

Comment: no, I want to make it more manageable uglify is not what I need.

Comment: @RohitSharma - that doesn't really do anything

Comment: i know bhai but mujhe issme is repetition hta ni hai like i am calling toggler.toggler again and again

Comment: oh, just realised, the id's in the handler are actually not what I thought - if there was a **consistent** pattern, then it's a simple job, but as is, you won't get much simpler and **readable** than you have

Answer (score 0):

What about to create an "equilalency object" ?

A 2 columns sheet of strings to refer from clicked to affected.

```
var equiv = {
  "--tb-bid-pickup-location"      : "--tb-bid-location-picker",
  "--tb-bid-destination-location" : "--tb-bid-location-picker",
  "--tb-bid-vehicle-type"         : "--tb-bid-truck-picker"
};

$( "[id^='--tb-bid']" ).on('keyup', function () {

  // Get the clicked ID.
  var thisID = $(this).attr("id");

  // If that id exist in the equiv object.
  if( equiv.hasOwnProperty(thisID) ){
    toggler.toggler("#"+equiv[thisID], 'pulse');
  }
});
```